# How can I compare if column equals in a matrix multiplication mannar?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, matrix-multiplication

I am using Keras (tensorflow as backend). What I want to do is to write a lambda layer that gets 2 tensor input and **compare every combination of 2 column** of them using Indicator function and produce a new tensor with 0-1 value. Here is an example.

**Input:** `x = K.variable(np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]))`,
           `y = K.variable(np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]))`

**Output**
`z=K.variable(np.array[[1,0],[0,1]])`

As far as I know, tensorflow provides `tf.equal()` to compare tensor in a elementwise way. But if I apply it here, I get

```
>>> z=tf.equal(x,y)
>>> K.eval(z)
array([[True,  True, True],
       [True,  True, True]], dtype=bool)
```

It only compares tensor in same position.

So my **questions** are:

**1.** Is there a tensorflow API to get my desired output or if I need to write my own function to complete it?

**2.** If it is the latter one, then there is another problem. I noticed that in **keras** the input is mini-batch, so the input format looks like: `(None, m, n)`. When writing my own method, how can I tackle with the first dimension, which is `None`?

Any reply would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting).

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]))
y = tf.constant(np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]))

x_ = tf.expand_dims(x, 0)
y_ = tf.expand_dims(y, 1)
res = tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x_, y_), axis=-1)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! it works! But I still wonder why the `tf.equal()` works here when the dimension of `x`and`y` are not the same. Could you explain more on that?

Comment: There is an explanation on broadcasting there: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting. (Edited my post to add the link there).